# java.util.zip.ZipException when running Ant script for Groovy project

Tags: grails, ant

I have this old Grails (1.3.1) project. It contains some Java, some Groovy, has an Ant script and Ivy dependency management. I've managed to open it in Eclipse and resolved some initial build errors, and now it looks fine. The Ant script has some targets (clean, compile, deploy etc), but for each of them, I run into the following:

(Ivy first retrieves a lot of dependencies)

> C:\[SOMECLASSPATH]\SomeClass.class: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>   [grailsTask] Unable to obtain resource from C:\[SOMECLASSPATH]\SomeClass.class:
>   [grailsTask] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Where [SOMECLASSPATH]\SomeClass varies, it is repeted for an seemlingy endless number of classes, and eventually I stop the process.

Comment: afaik, ant tries to handle `SomeClass.class` as zip file, which it is not. Can you remove it from the classpath?

Comment: Late comment, but I solved my problem by opening the project in NetBeans with the groovy/grails plugin installed. It managed to find a grails project, while Eclipse didn't. 
The jar-files downloaded by Ivy actually contained html saying that codehaus has closed, so no wonder grails coudn't make sense of them. I replaced the codehaus repo references with others and then I got the real jars.